# Adding a list as new column to csv file

Tags: python, csv, append

I have a list of items and I want to write it in my existing csv as new column.

```
mylist=['in','out','out','in']

with open('my.csv','w') as file:
   writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
   writer.writerows(mylist)


first_column       2nd_col
=====               ====
AMPHENOL           AMPHENOL

AMPHENOL           MOLEX
NEXANS             MOLEX
                   NEXANS
AMPHENOL
RS

RS

MPHENOL
```

This is what I actually have,in the same there will me more cols with different no of rows on every iteration. What I want is in the screenshot ==== is just for demonstration.

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjI3U.png)

Comment: show your attempts

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '''rizwan,10
arsalan,30
ali,40
suffiyan,60'''
s = s.split('\n')
mylist=['in','out','out','in']
for i, v in enumerate(mylist):
    s[i] += ',' + v
print('\n'.join(s))
```

Output

```
rizwan,10,in
arsalan,30,out
ali,40,out
suffiyan,60,in
```

In your case, you need to read your file and write to it.

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    s = file.read()
s = s.split('\n')
mylist=['in','out','out','in']
for i, v in enumerate(mylist):
    s[i+2] += ',' + v
with open('test.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(s))
```

Comment: what is s[i+2] if no of columns in csv are changing at every loop iteration

Comment: @tayyabmahboob `s[i+2]` is to make sure the element will be filedl in the right line.

Comment: @tayyabmahboob I thought `mycsv` is in your `csv` file, if it is not then use `s[i+1]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library is pretty good for that:

```
In [274]: mylist=['in','out','out','in']                                                                        

In [275]: df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', sep=',', header=None)                                                          

In [276]: df['new_col'] = mylist                                                                                

In [277]: df.to_csv('my.csv', sep=',', index=None, header=False)
```

The final csv file contents:

```
rizwan,10,in
arsalan,30,out
ali,40,out
suffiyan,60,in
```

Comment: In this case no of rows of each column should be equal.otherwise it throw an error.In my case no of rows are different.above csv is just an example

Comment: @tayyabmahboob, So update your question properly with appropriate sample and conditions - we are not guessing here

Comment: ,now in above mentioned condition what do you suggest

Comment: @tayyabmahboob, post the actual output with a proper formatting - it's unclear whether your `=====` is the real content or just your demonstration signs